# Android communication between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

http://pastebin.com/p9FCCMX1I'm trying to send data from one fragment to another fragment through an activity.
It's possible to send data from GroupFragment to ChatActivity (id contains correct value) but when it reaches:

```
@Override
public void respond(String id) {
    interfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity.respond(id);
}
```

In my ChatActivity it throws an NUllPointException and i dont know how to make it work?

(I tried to make it easier for you to read when I only pasted parts of the code, was friendly and correct me if it didn't help! For all code: "http://pastebin.com/p9FCCMX1")

ChatActivity:

```
public class ChatActivity extends Activity implements
    GroupFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
    //ChatFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
    GroupFragment.InterfaceDataCommunicator {

    public InterfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity interfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity;

    @Override
    public void respond(String id) {
        interfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity.respond(id);
    }

    public interface InterfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity {
        public void respond(String id);
    }
}
```

GroupFragment:

```
public class GroupFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    public InterfaceDataCommunicator interfaceDataCommunicater;
    ...../


    public void CreateNewGroup(String groupName) {

        Map<String, Group> newGroup = new HashMap<>();

        Firebase  firebaserootRef = new Firebase("https://luminous-heat-420.firebaseio.com");

        Firebase firebaseGroup = firebaserootRef.child("").push();

        Group group = new Group();

        group.SetID(firebaseGroup.getKey());
        group.SetName(groupName);

        String id = firebaseGroup.getKey();
        firebaseGroup.child("id").setValue(group.GetId());
        firebaseGroup.child("name").setValue(group.GetName());

        newGroup.put(id, group);

        interfaceDataCommunicater.respond(group.GetId());
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }

        try {
            interfaceDataCommunicater = (InterfaceDataCommunicator) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException c) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement InterfaceDataCommunicator");
        }
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

    public interface InterfaceDataCommunicator{
        public void respond(String id);
    }
}
```

ChatFragment:

```
public class ChatFragment extends Fragment implements
    View.OnClickListener,
    ChatActivity.InterfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity {

    public ChatActivity.InterfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity
           interfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity; 

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }

        try {
            interfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity = (ChatActivity
               .InterfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity) activity;    
        } catch (ClassCastException c) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement InterfaceDataCommunicator");
        }
    }


    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

    @Override
    public void respond(String id) {
        this.groupID = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using broadcasts instead of interfaces

Comment: where do you initialize field `interfaceDataCommunicatorFromActivity` ? I mean you do not set any value to that field in Activity, so it is obvious to get null pointer exception there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `interfaceDataComunicatorFromActivity` in your activity is useless and you're getting a NPE because there's no reference to it. If you just want the id of your group in your `ChatFragment`, just pass it via `setter` in your `ChangeToChatFragment()`:

```
public void ChangeToChatFragment(String groupId) {
    ChatFragment groupFragment = ChatFragment.newInstance("", "");
    groupFragment.setGroupId(groupId);
    FragmentManager fM = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fT = fM.beginTransaction();
    fT.replace(R.id.container_chat, groupFragment, null);
    fT.addToBackStack("go to chat fragmement");
    fT.commit();
}
```

**EDIT:**

In your `ChatFragment` add:

```
public void setGroupId(String groupId){
   this.groupId = groupId;
}
```

Then pass your `groupId` as a parameter to `ChangeToChatFragment`

Comment: Thx for the  fast answer and your solution worked but just to clarify for others who have the same problem, i needed to add a SetGroupID(String groupId) {return this.group = groupId; } in my ChatFragment (the class i was seending the string to)...